# Is それ何語 the informal version of それは何語ですか?

Tags: particles, parts-of-speech

I heard (maybe I misheard) someone say それ何語? It seems to be the informal version of それは何語ですか？ However, I was a bit surprised to see は ommited.

Is それ何語 a very informal version of それは何語ですか? Is the omission of は common in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「何語」, when pronounced 「な**に**ご」, means "what language".

「何語」, when pronounced 「な**ん**ご」, however, means "how many words".

In real life, the former would be used far more often than the latter.  Since you provided no context, however, we have no way of knowing which one it is for sure.

Moving on to the topic of particle omission, **「は」 (along with 「を」) are among the most often omitted particles in informal speech**.

Thus, 「それ何語?」 said with a rising intonation at the end would be an informal version of 「それは何語ですか?」 .

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes.

There are many ways that general grammar rules are "broken" in informal/casual Japanese. Oftentimes parts of the sentence or words are omitted because they're assumed. In this case we get "that" and "what language" with an inflection that makes it a question. The grammar is not *proper* but the listener still understands what the question is. A more common example of this is the phrase `何それ?`, "What's that?"

One should only dip into using these kinds of contractions when they are very comfortable with the language and feel that they have a friendly, casual relationship with the person they're talking to. In the mean time, it's good to know that for understanding purposes.